# Python ValueError inherited custom exception behavior

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, valueerror

I define my base `Error` exception inheriting the `Exception` class,
then I define a custom exception inheriting `Error`:

```
class Error(Exception):                                                                                                                           
    pass                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                  
class ValueTooSmallError(Error):                                                                                                                  
    pass                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                        
number = 10  # put a number above this                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                  
while True:                                                                                                                                       
    try:                                                                                                                                          
        i_num = int(input("Enter a number: "))                                                                                                        
        if i_num < number:                                                                                                                        
            raise ValueTooSmallError                                                                                                              
        break                                                                                                                                     
    except ValueTooSmallError:                                                                                                                    
        print("This value is too small, try again!")                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                  
print("Ok.")
```

It works as expected:

```
Enter a number: 1
This value is too small, try again!
Enter a number: 11
OK.
```

With the same principle, `ValueError` exception inherits the `Exception` class, then I define a custom exception inheriting ValueError:

```
class myValueError(ValueError):                                                                                                                   
    pass      
                                                                                                                               
while True:                                                                                                                                       
    try:                                                                                                                                          
        i_num = int(input("Enter a number: "))                                                                                                    
    except myValueError:                                                                                                                          
        print("this is a string, try again!")                                                                                                     
        raise myValueError
```

But in this case:

```
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: "asd"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    i_num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"asd"'
```

Why I don't see the `myValueError` print, and I see instead `ValueError`?

Comment: First you need to catch the ValueError and then you can raise myValueError. You can't catch myValueError before you have raised it.

Answer (score 0):

In your second snippet it raises the ValueError exception, not the myValueError exception.

Comment: But this is unexpected, as I ask to raise `myValueError`

Comment: You only ask it to raise `myValueError` when it catches a `myValueError`. What I think you want is to raise `myValueError` when it catches `ValueError`. Try changing `except myValueError:` to `except ValueError:` and see if that's the behaviour you did expect.

Comment: I did. Now it works and myValueError is *raised*, but then I don't understand how to *catch* it